# How to copy files from an encrypted S3 bucket to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, boto, gsutil

I need to sync some files between an encrypted (S3-SSE) S3 bucket and a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

The task sounds simple, as `gsutil` supports S3, but unfortunately it seems it does not support SSE:

> Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4.

**Is there an easy way to sync files between an encrypted (S3-SSE) S3 bucket and a Google Cloud Storage bucket (apart from writing our own script)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As gsutil doesn't currently support Signature Version 4, there doesn't look to be an "easy" way (i.e. without writing a script of your own) to sync files between your two buckets.  A naive solution might simply chain together the s3 cli and gsutil tools for each copy, using your machine as the middleman for a daisy-chain approach as gsutil already does for cross-cloud-provider copies.

Comment: Thanks, that was I was afraid of. :(